# strcmp repeated call failure

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

I'm writing a simple shell program in C that adds a few internal commands and if the input is not one of those will fork and execute a standard command. When I use strcmp to compare my input to the various commands, it fails on repeated uses. I think something is wrong with my parsing algorithm since the comparisons are really simple but only fail on repeated unquoted commands. Input is parsed to keep quoted strings together and otherwise separate by spaces. Note from the criteria is that single quotes and double quotes will not be nested.

The parameters of this method are the input from stdin using getline and 0.

```
char** strparse(char* str, int* size)
{
    char** array = NULL;
    char* temp = strdupa(str);
    char* delimquotes = "\"\'";
    char* token = NULL;
    bool inquote = temp[0] == '\'' || temp[0] == '"';
    *size = 0;
    while ((token = strsep(&temp, delimquotes)))
    {
        if(!strlen(token))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (inquote)
        {
            (*size)++;
            array = realloc(array, (*size) * sizeof(char*));
            if (array)
            {
                array[(*size)-1] = token;
            }
            else
            {
                free(array);
                free(temp);
                free(token);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            char* temp2 = strdupa(token);
            char* delimspace = " ";
            char* token2 = NULL;
            while ((token2 = strsep(&temp2, delimspace)))
            {
                if(!strlen(token2))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                (*size)++;
                array = realloc(array, (*size) * sizeof(char*));
                if (array)
                {
                    array[(*size)-1] = token2;
                }
                else
                {
                    free(array);
                    free(temp);
                    free(temp2);
                    free(token);
                    free(token2);
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
        }
        inquote = !inquote;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Testing the returned array at index 0 is returning the exact same thing for subsequent commands. I'm thoroughly confused as to why this only works with quoted input.

EDIT: Checking the output is done with `printf("-%d-%s-\n", i, parsed[i]);`, there are no trailing or leading spaces in working and nonworking cases.

EDIT2: strcmp section.

```
            char** parsed = strparse(line, &size);
            if (size <= 0)
            {
                    commandcount--;
                    free(line);
                    free(parsed);
                    continue;
            }
            else
            {
                    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    {
                            printf("-%d-%s-\n", i, parsed[i]);
                    }
                    commands = realloc(commands, commandcount * sizeof(char*));
                    commands[commandcount-1] = line;
                    if (!strcmp(parsed[0], "verbose"))
                    {
                            verbose(size, parsed);
                    }
                    else if (!strcmp(parsed[0], "help"))
                    {
                            help(size, parsed);
                    }
                    else if (!strcmp(parsed[0], "history"))
                    {
                            history(size, parsed);
                    }
                    else if (!strcmp(parsed[0], "quit"))
                    {
                            quit(size, parsed);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            printf("NO MATCH\n");
                    }
            }
```

EDIT: The reallocation of commands is causing the error. I think I need a triple pointer.

Comment: I don't see any `strcmp()` in the code...

Comment: Added it to the post. The new line (not null) character is removed above that incase that matters.
EDIT: You dont remove the null character

Comment: BTW `free(temp);` : `temp` may have been changed by the `strsep`. `free(token)` : It has released an invalid value to do or a double release.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're telling me to fix here. All frees are done inside the cleanup code because of the required command history that needs persistance throughout the program. The frees inside strparse are only there incase of allocation errors.

Comment: It just does not manifest Because It do not have failed to `realloc`.

Comment: The problem is with the realloc of commands (just tested without that and it works). I believe that my history storage is broken.

Comment: Q: Is `token` hold  address that address of return of malloc(or realloc) ?

Comment: `token` holds the address of whatever strsep returns. I would assume this is a malloc'd array.

Comment: address pointed to by the token is part of the memory that is reserved.

Comment: see small test code : http://ideone.com/EpZu42

Comment: Oh I see, that's very helpful. I think I have a fix for it.